# Regular Expression for parsing PHP annotations containing multiple lines and markup

Tags: regex, php5

I am writing a regular expression for parsing PHP annotations in a flexible way.
I'd like to accomplish all the goals listed above with one single expression. So I would appreciate any suggestions about the quality of it (in terms of corner cases, performance, best practices and correctness).

**PCRE expression:**

```
/[\*\s]*@(?P<name>\w+[\\\w]*?)(?:\s|\()
(?P<value>
  (?:[\/\w\s\"\<\>\_\#\=\-\.\'\{\}:;,\*\(\)\[\]]*[^\R\*\s\/\)])
)?
(?:\s | $|\))/gsxmu
```

**Goals of the regular expression:**

- List all annotations with their values
- Values can be multi-lined and have markup (html, json or markdown)
- The initial space + * of each line should be removed from the value
- Many annotations can be in the same line
- Annotation names can be namespaced

**Sample PHPDoc string:**

> ```
> /**
>  * Description
>  * 
>  * @Tag name name @annotation beee @aaf dsfsd fgdg
>  * @Tag name name {"json":"dfsf"}
>  * @Tag asdasd <html> #markdown ==markdown== __markdown__
>  * - markdown
>  * > mark 1
> .mark
> "string"
> 'string'
>  * @Annotation()
>  * @Tag name name @annotation beee @aaf dsfsd fgdg <markdown> #markdown ==markdown==
>  * @a() @b("name") @c()
>  * @Annotation\Name("var1()", "var2") @n("name()_name")
>  * @Annotation(["var1", "var2"], "var3")
>  * @Annotation\Filter\Name(["var1", "var2"], "var3", {"var4": "var5"})
>  * @Annotation(
>  *    ["GET", "POST"]
>    ) @Name({"name": "Tomas"})
>  * @Tag name name
>  */
> ```

Expected result:

> ```
> <?php
>
> array(
>   [
>       'name' => 'Tag',
>       'value' => 'name name'
>   ],
>   [
>       'name' => 'annotation',
>       'value' => 'bee'
>   ],
>   [
>       'name' => 'aaf',
>       'value' => 'dsfsd fgdg'
>   ]
>   // ... and so on... (see live example)
> );
> ```

A live demo can be found [here](https://regex101.com/r/zU1eQ5/7).

Comment: Why is `\R` there?

Answer (score 1):

1. If you're using it in a PHP code, you are not restricted to using `/` as the pattern delimiter. Using any other character, such as `~` or `%` frees you of using `\/` everywhere, thereby shortening it.
2. I don't know what `\R` is meant to do there, but I think it was supposed to be `\r`. If so, you do not need it at all.
3. For the annotation name parameter match, you can just specify that it start with a `\w` character, followed by a lazy match on `[\w\\]` character set. Even using `[\w\\]+` as the name parameter would not be wrong.
4. When inside a character set, you absolutely do not need to escape any characters other than the closing square bracket (`]`) and the exponent (`^`) if it is the first character. You can move the hyphen (`-`) to either the beginning or the end. So, the whole `value` group reduces to

   ```
   (?P<value>(?:[-/\w\s"<>_#=.'{}:;,*()[\]]*[^*\s/)]))?
   ```

   PS: You might need to escape *at most* one of `'` or `"` depending on how you are using the pattern in your code.
5. In the above, it appears you want to match everything except the next `@` character, so; `[^@]*` would be my next suggestion.
6. Towards the end of you pattern, you have: `(?:\s | $|\))` which could become: `(?:\s+|$|\))` or simply `(?:\s+|\))` since you would not be needing the anchor at all.
7. You are not counting on a string like:

   ```
   @name    (something)
   ```

   where, you receive `name` and `\s\s\s(something` as resulting value (`\s` is space literal). This can be kept under check by setting `\s*\(?` instead of `(?:\s|\()`. This might also not be the intended behaviour from the user, which is why I kept this suggestion at the end.

---

```
[*\s]* # multiple space or asterisk characters
@ # followed by the @ sign which
(?P<name>[\w\\]+) # has a string of \w or \ characters following it
\s*\(? # separated by spaces and maybe opening parenthesis
  (?P<value> # store the value attached to the named annotation
    (?:
      [^@]* # value is made of enlisted characters
      [^*\s/)] # but does not end with
    )
  )? # the value is optional parameter
(?:\s|$|\)) # succeded by one of these
```